# Error en CMD / Terminal de Windows 10 al intentar ejecutar archivo

Tags: cmd, windows10, terminal

Pues la cosa es esa. Quiero probar ApacheKafka desde mi PC con windows 10.
Abro el cmd como administrador y me dirijo a la carpeta con:

```
C:\>cd KafkaApache\kafka_2.13-2.6.0
```

Tras esto, me encuentro en esta carpeta:
[image: Carpeta]

Cuando pongo en el cmd la ruta:

```
> .\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
```

no inicia el .bat con las properties indicadas, sino que me dice que no se ha encontrado la ruta especificada. No sé cómo solucionarlo, y he probado a poner la ruta de varias maneras (sin punto, con punto, con /...), pero nada funciona.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo intentas ejecutar un archivo bat pasándole un parámetro.

Te hago presente que en tu intento solo le pasas un directorio al cmd sin especificar que cosa debe hacer con él y normalmente se debe colocar una instrucción, por ejemplo `cd directorio` sirve para moverse a un directorio.

Olvidaste el comando `start` necesario para ejecutar el archivo bat. Lo que intentas hacer se hace así:

```
start directorio parametro
```

El punto `.\` no es necesario, puedes usar un directorio parcial como `bin\win\start.bat` si te encuentras ubicado en la carpeta que contiene `bin`, y también puedes utilizar un directorio completo como el siguiente `C:\apache\bin\win\start.bat`.